# how to prove this function is a probability measure in $U_B$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega, U, P)$ be a probability space. and $B\in U$, $P(B)\gt 0$

$U_B =\{A: A=B\cap C, C\in U\}$

its class in $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and

$P_B : U_B \to \Bbb R$

$A \to P_B(A)=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

how to prove this function is a measurable space in $U_B$

---

What I know that is the following;

measurable space is defined as

$U$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $\Omega$

$P: U  \to [0,1]$

$A \to P(A)$

i)  $\forall A \in U$, $P(A) \ge 0$

ii) $P(\Omega)=1$

iii)$A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$

$P(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\sum^\infty_{n=1)} P(A_n)$

---

Thank you for helping :)